# Как реализовать std::lock чтобы он получил std::array<std::mutex> и заблокировал все мьютексы?

Tags: c++, многопоточность

необходимо заблокировать N мотехов но писать токио код не хочется.

```
std::lock(arr[0], arr[1], ...., arr[N-1]);
```

Если разбежаться над всеми мьютексами и вызвать lock()

```
for(auto& mtx : arr)
{
     mtx.lock();
}
```

это может привести к взаимоблокировки.

Comment: А зачем вам столько мьютексов? Может получится сделать попроще?

Comment: Создайте ещё один мютекс, корневой.

Comment: скажем ест 16 потоков, каждый  из них имеет свои данные но в коких та случиях которые стречаютса не чсто, они начинаеют не испозовать данные друг друга, в этих сучьях надо заблокировать все, но когда поток изпользует свои данные нужно заблокировать только один мутекс.

Comment: Так стандартный [std::lock](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/lock) так умеет из коробки.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
namespace details
{

template<typename T, size_t N, size_t ... Indexes>
void lock_all_impl(std::array<T, N> & muts, std::index_sequence<Indexes...>)
{
    std::lock(muts[Indexes]...);
}

}//end of namespace details

template<typename T, size_t N>
void lock_all(std::array<T, N> & muts)
{
    details::lock_all_impl(muts, std::make_index_sequence<N>());
}

//использование:
std::array<std::mutex, mutex_count> arr;
lock_all(arr);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
mutex mutboss;
array<mutex> arrmut;
condition_variable sigboss;
bool flagwaitsignal = false ;
size_t guest_count = 0;
mutex mutguests;

void GlobalLock(){
  mutboss.lock();
  unique_lock<std::mutex> lock(mutguests);
  while(guest_count) {
    flagwaitsignal = true ;
    sigboss.wait(lock); } }

void GlobalUnLock(){
  mutboss.unlock();  }

void PassIn(size_t ind){
  mutboss.lock();
  mutguests.lock();
  ++guest_count;
  mutguests.unlock();
  mutboss.unlock();
  arrmut[ind].lock();    }

void PassOut(size_t ind){
  arrmut[ind].unlock();
  mutguests.lock();
  --guest_count;
  if(flagwaitsignal and guest_count == 0) {
    flagwaitsignal = false; 
    sigboss.notify_one(); }
  mutguests.unlock(); }
```

Всё написано на `члаз` - синтаксис может быть неправильный, но это классическая реализация, всё на память.